# How to take a screenshot of a pickerViewController and UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a `TableView` who presents a `PickerViewController` on a `ViewController`. The ViewController show some Images and a button than triggering an action. I want that this action takes a screenshot as the screenshot that is provided by Apple.
Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func share(){

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(thePicker.view.frame.size)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    thePicker.view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
    present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[This image is the result of using the screenshot provided by Apple (side + home button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yrMv.png)[This image is result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwXm3.jpg)

Comment: Share screenshot of the view controller.

Comment: Search for 'UIView screenshot.'

Comment: @RajeshkumarR I just shared the images.

Answer (score 1):

you should write a extension for view's screenshot.Extension's return value is UIImage.You can print UIImage to UIImageview. Also if you want to, you can call here a button action.

```
import UIKit


class VideoContentController: UIViewController{
      override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.viewScreenShot()
    }
     func viewScreenShot()
    {
     let image = self.youtView.takeScreenShot()
     self.yourImageView.image = image
    }


}    

extension UIView {

        func takeScreenShot() -> UIImage {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

            drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

            // old style: layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())

            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return image!
        }
    }
```

**Enjoy it :)**

Comment: i am using my facebook share project.Which code does not work @MarcoGonzalez

Comment: The code can make a screenshot, but it just of the View controller and I need a screenshot of the View Controller and the PickerViewController. I just post the photos on my original question.

Comment: The above code does not get the screenshot of the UIViewController.it does take a screenshot of the UIIView. If you can add UIPickerView to the UIView. You can take screenshot of the UIPickerView in the UIView

Answer (score 1):

```
func ScreenCapturing() 
{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation so that the poster and others can understand your solution.