# iOS Capture Screenshot and Save to Storage

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to capture screenshot iOS App and write to storage.  I've read through a couple tutorials, and I have confirmed the func captureScreenshot works, but having trouble trying to save to Data.

```
    public static func captureScreenshot() -> UIImage{
    let layer = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.layer
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    // Creates UIImage of same size as view
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);
    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return screenshot!
}
```

Here I call the captureScreenshot method to get the UIImage and save it:

```
    let localFile : UIImage = GlobalFunction.captureScreenshot()

    if let image = localFile {
        if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
            let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.png")
            try? data.write(to: filename)
        }
    }
```

Here is the error:

```
 Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UIImage'
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778797/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-pickerviewcontroller-and-uiview/42786207#42786207

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UIImage'

...is telling you that you can't say `if let` in this line:

```
let localFile : UIImage = GlobalFunction.captureScreenshot()
if let image = localFile {
```

That's because your `captureScreenshot` returns a UIImage, not a `UIImage?`. And your `localFile` is therefore also a UIImage (as your declaration states), not a `UIImage?`

Since `localFile` is not an Optional, there is no Optional to unwrap, which is what `if let` does. So you don't need the intermediary `localFile` variable. (I don't know why you called it that, since a UIImage is not a file. But whatever.) Just say

```
let image = GlobalFunction.captureScreenshot()
if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.png")
    try? data.write(to: filename)
}
```